# How to implement and insert value SQL specialization/generalization

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have my table with these 3 entities: student, lecturer and person. Person will be the parent that holds common attributes of student and lecturer. This is my database design, is this a correct way of implementing specialization?

### Person

personID int Primary key,
Role varchar(10) ,
Name varchar(50),
email varchar(255)

### Student

studentID int,
intake  varchar(50),
major varchar( 50) ,
personID int reference person(personID)

### Lecturer

LecturerID int ,
Skill varchar(50),
Qualification varchar(50) ,
personID int reference person(personID)

The above of the table, is this the correct way to implement generalization/specialization ? If it is, How do I insert a new value to the database when a new student enrolls?

Comment: Your db is both in mysql and sql-server? Remove unnecessary tags.

Comment: Please have a look at the following post : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/how-to-model-inheritance-of-two-tables-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally have the right idea (or, at least, one of the common idioms to implement such a database schema). If your [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) supports it, I'd use an enum for the `role` column (MySQL, e.g., does. MS SQL Server does not). If it doesn't I'd add a check constraint to achieve a similar effect and make sure you don't get any junk inserted there.

Insertion should be done to the base table (`person`) first and only then to the specialization tables (`student` or `lecturer`). E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO person 
VALUES (1, 'student', 'hiboss', 'hiboss@example.com');

INSERT INTO student
VALUES (100, 'intake', 'computer science', 1);
```

Comment: Okay, so there is no any other way like using  "select" to join the table and insert the value. Instead, I need to create a Trigger that is after insert  for base table, then get Primary key (Assume that primary key is auto increment) from inserted base table and pass it to specialization table